# How to save tableview rows to a file and reload to tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, save, tableview

I have a simple tableview and I populated it with a text.field :

```
@interface ListaDeProdutosTableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *produtos;

@end

@implementation ListaDeProdutosTableViewController
```

Now I want to save this rows to a file (to persist data) and read it back to tableview. How can I do this?

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does it mean that I want to save this rows to a file? Do you want to save content of your tableview cell?

Comment: My tableview is made by 1 dynamic prototype cell. The user inputs products one by one to the tableview. What I want is to  save  that list to a file to persistent data. When the user can retrieve the saved list to tableview, edit this list and save it again. My difficult is to access the content of this array using self.produtos, why I can't access its contents? When I try to reference self.produtos [0] ( Is it an array, correct? Or is a different type of array? ) I have exception error and the content seems like a memory address 0x7506603..

Comment: Yes Bhanu, I want to save content of my tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to save, but here's an example how to save object to file and read it later:

```
- (NSString *)cachePath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)cacheObject:(NSString *)objectId withData:(SomeClass *)objectData{
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectData];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/someobject-%@.cache", [self cachePath], objectId];
    [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}

- (SomeClass *)getObjectCache:(NSString *)objectId {
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/someobject-%@.cache", [self cachePath], objectId];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    if (!data) {
        return nil;
    }
    SomeClass *object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    return object;
}
```